# First steps on troubleshooting crashes for aheadless pi?

Tags: linux, headless

I use a Raspberry Pi 4 8 GB as a headless server to run stuff like `pihole`, `nextcloud`, `wireguard`, etc

Ever since I switched from booting and operating from an SD card to an external SSD drive over USB, I find it crashes quite more often (once or twice a week with the SSD vs just me physically crashing into it and unplugging something with the SD card)

What would be the first steps in troubleshooting this issue? Any logs I could check upon boot up to see if I'm having a power issue or if some service is hanging the pi or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by checking the PSU rating is enough for worst case Pi and SSD simultaneous current draw. I've seen many problems where random reboots are due to under rated PSUs, especially with external disks.

The particular "fun", is that you can have a system which works fine most of the time, but when you get an unfortunate combination of CPU usage and disk activity, the increased power draw causes the voltage to drop and the system to reboot.

Update: I had exactly this problem yesterday when trying to swap to a new SSD for a large database.  The original had worked fine for three years, but I could just not get the copy to work, with the target persistently unmounting and remounting read-only. Added a powered hub, and I was done in under 20s. And with just the new disc, all seems stable.  Current draw of both was simply too high...

Comment: I'd second this. You might just have a faulty SSD, but by far the most likely reason for these random crashes is due to your power supply not being up to the job.

Comment: Right now it is a 15W PSU (5v 3a) which I figured to be plenty, but maybe the brick is not actually delivering that consistently.

Shame, I would have loved avoiding an external supply/powered hub to keep cable clutter to a minimum

Comment: @ManuelPedroGómezCastro Try it with a powered hub, and if it works stably, try another PSU.